# Spring Boot Repository decorator not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, annotations, repository

I have multi module Spring Boot appliction with Kotlin and Exposed for data layer. Modules are Core, Service and Data. References between modules are Core everywhere, data in Service and Service in root app. @Component and @Service anotations working fine. But @Repository annotation gives me: Error creating bean with name... UnsatisfiedDependencyException... If I change @Repository annotation to @Component annotation, error disappear and everything seems to work fine. What is wrong with my configuration?

Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.mjana.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJdbcRepositories("com.mjana.data.*")
@Configuration
class ExampleapiApplication {
    @Bean
    open fun transactionManager(dataSource: DataSource) = SpringTransactionManager(dataSource)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ExampleapiApplication>(*args)
}
```

Main App pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
    <artifactId>exampleapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>exampleapi</name>
    <description>Example Api</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.71</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Core pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.71</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Data pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
    <artifactId>data</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.71</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>exposed</id>
            <name>exposed</name>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
            <artifactId>exposed-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Service pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.71</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mjana</groupId>
            <artifactId>data</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i belive `@Bean` annotated functions should be placed in a `@Configuration` annotated class. Can't see how a bean can be initiated before your applications has even run.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I added Configuration annotation but result is the same.

Comment: You clearly didn't read what i posted, you just placed the `@Configuration` on the main class which was NOT what i wrote. I wrote that the `@Bean` needs to be instantiated in a `@Configuration` annotated class. That means its own class, that is scanned by the application at startup.

There are several faults, in your multi module project, there is no pom.xml that contains the `<module>` tag. If this is your first time building a spring boot application i recommend to do a simple hello world app without a multi module project.

good luck

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, I Am C# developer, completely new to kotlin/java world. 1. I found several examples where Configuration annotation was on main class. What is wrong about that? 2. Originally I had modules in main pom, but I got circular dependency errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005303/spring-boot-kotlin-circular-dependency/61007482#61007482. 3. I find out that If I set my Repository class as open it start working with Repository annotation.

Comment: You get circular dependencies because pom.xml's are a tree like structure. The master pom.xml should not contain any concrete dependencies. Your master pom does not have any concrete code, hence it should not have any dependencies. It can however have `dependency management`. Master pom should have reference to all child modules, and then have dependency management which means simple a declaration of what dependencies all child modules should have. So that two child modules dont have the same dependency but different versions.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Can I ask for a reference to a multi module project that has a similar structure to what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: the official maven documentation http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository class has to be set as open.